# How determine what CSS selector to use from my HTML source code?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

The wordpress theme I've been using has been acting up so I'm trying my hand at editing my site using style sheets (I've 0 experience with html or CSS). I'm finding the googling process to discover the selector names I must use to edit each element within my site very time consuming so I've started looking at the source code to try and identify the selector I need.

For the example below I'm looking to change the signup form's button's background colour.

```
<div class="notif">
            <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
            <div id="mc_embed_signup_appstage">
                <form action="http://HUDKingPro.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=0c2c35acf6b36619d521176a9&id=8d4d76b2db" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form_appstage" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank">
                                                    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL_appstage" placeholder="Enter your email address" required />
                            <input type="submit" value="Notify me !" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe_appstage" class="button" />
```

So far using the selectors I have identified I've come up with this but it doesn't appear to work, is there a methodology for identifying the CSS selector from the HTML source code?

```
#notif input {
background: #1A1A18;
}
```

Apologies if this is overly naive, I've an app to launch for next week so I've had insufficient time to develop a thorough understanding of CSS.

Comment: @Yvette I'm looking in to this now thanks, does this not run in to the same problem of not knowing what selectors to use for each element I wish to edit?

Comment: @Yvette Ye that makes sense. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Yvette The theme is very specific for selling apps although there are others I can pay for (I cheaped out on a free one). I'm fine for links for now, if I don't figure this out I'll likely just reinstall the theme and switch if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use the class the button has? i.e. `.button`

So it will be:

```
.notif .button {
    background: #1A1A18;
}
```

Your div has `<div class="notif">` therefore you're CSS is invalid with the `#`
You use `.` for classes and `#` for id's.

**Edit**

It's taking this stylesheet http://hudkingpro.com/wp-content/themes/apptamin-a-hor/yourstyles-example4.css

Edit the background colours by line 76 or:

This is the class or input you want to edit:

```
.notif input#mc-embedded-subscribe_appstage{
    background: #1A1A18 !important;
}
```

Add the above to the Appearance - Editor.

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid. It's possible the problem with the theme could be affecting this. The reason I'm having to use CSS is because the themes main colour scheme got stuck on blue so I'm going through each element one by one changing it from blue to what I want, although so far the CCS code usually overwrites the theme's settings.

Comment: That's weird.Are you using the theme's stylesheets or your own?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think I'm using the themes, I just clicked on appearance > edit CSS.

Comment: Oh ok so it should be the theme's. Can we maybe see a link to your site for the button?

Comment: I updated my answer, it's using a specific stylesheet you can edit or just apply !important to your custom styles in the editor.

Comment: This worked thanks.
How did you identify what selector to use? What parts of the html do I take when applying this to different sections of code?

Comment: I highly recommend using Google Chrome's element inspector. It shows you the styles applied for each HTML element which will make your life easier when editing theme's or CSS. You can also use Firefox but I find it lagging at times. Just right click and inspect the element, the CSS will be shown on the right column.

Comment: Your last sentence answers my question better than your answer. Although the !important thing appears to make the difference with this example. Thanks.

Comment: I should have said how I found the CSS styles because that's what you wanted! But yea the !important is really useful to override other CSS. Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

`#` is for IDs, whereas you have `class="notif"`. Additionally, without further restriction it will affect the email input as well as the submit button.

So try `.notif input[type=submit]`

Comment: I've tried the code below to no avail. Rather than the looking for the selector for this specific case I'm looking for a methodology to identify what the selector needed is from the html, if this exists.

.notif input[type=submit] {
 background: #1A1A18;
}